# What is this cylindrical three-legged component?

Tags: identification

It looks like a capacitor, but from my testing it is probably a resistor.

This is the board I removed it from.

[image: What is this]

It is marked VW-1 HF(OR T)

[image: One side board]

[image: Second side board]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a tapped inductor (autotransformer), used as part of a switchmode power converter. Inside, it has a ferrite core shaped like a bobbin with some wire wrapped around it, and then the whole thing was covered with heat-shrink tubing.

Comment: WOW that was fast. Thanks.I am getting 0.6Ω L=0.03mH 1 (long)-2 pins, 2.1Ω L=0.62mH 1(long)-3pins and 2.6Ω L=0.91mH 2-3 pins,  Is this right? How can i say if this is faulty?

Comment: That sounds about right for a part that size.

Comment: How can i say if this is faulty?

Comment: Based on your measurements, it doesn't sound like it is. What is the application? Based on the fact that two of the external wires are connected directly to the coil, I'm guessing a high-frequency lamp driver of some sort.

Comment: There is a module that creates mist out of water, but doesnt get any voltage and this coil is just before that module.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. This circuit is driving the ultrasonic transducer.